# Auth0 get meta_data not authenticated

Tags: ios, swift, auth0, auth0-lock

I'm using Auth0 to authenticate my users using my ios app and Iv'e been following the docs on getting the user meta data but it doesn't work when I try it. Following the docs, this is the method that I've written:

#### AuthenticationViewController

```
    @IBAction func showLogin(_ sender: UIButton) {
        guard let clientInfo = plistValues(bundle: Bundle.main) else { return }
        Auth0
            .webAuth()
            .scope("openid profile read:current_user")
            .audience("https://" + clientInfo.domain + "/userinfo")
            .start {
                switch $0 {
                case .failure(let error):
                    Loaf("Something went wrong, please try again!", state: .error, location: .bottom, presentingDirection: .vertical, dismissingDirection: .vertical, sender: self).show()
                    print("---WEBAUTH---", error)
                case .success(let credentials):
                    if(!SessionManager.shared.store(credentials: credentials)) {
                        print("Failed to store credentials")
                    } else {
                        SessionManager.shared.retrieveProfile { error in
                            if let error = error {
                                print("---RETRIEVE PROFILE---", error)
                            } else {
                                SessionManager.shared.getMetaData { (error) in
                                    if let error = error {
                                        print("---GETMETADATA---", error)
                                    } else {
                                        DispatchQueue.main.async {
                                            self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "authenticate", sender: self)
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
        }
    }
```

#### Session Manager

```
class SessionManager {
    static let shared = SessionManager()
    private let authentication = Auth0.authentication()
    let credentialsManager: CredentialsManager!
    var profile: UserInfo?
    var credentials: Credentials?
    var patchMode: Bool = false

    private init () {
        self.credentialsManager = CredentialsManager(authentication: Auth0.authentication())
        _ = self.authentication.logging(enabled: true)
    }

    func retrieveProfile(_ callback: @escaping (Error?) -> ()) {
        guard let accessToken = self.credentials?.accessToken
            else { return callback(CredentialsManagerError.noCredentials) }
        self.authentication
            .userInfo(withAccessToken: accessToken)
            .start { result in
                switch(result) {
                case .success(let profile):
                    self.profile = profile
                    callback(nil)
                case .failure(let error):
                    callback(error)
                }
        }
    }

    func getMetaData(_ callback: @escaping (Error?) -> ()) {
        guard let accessToken = self.credentials?.accessToken
            else { return callback(CredentialsManagerError.noCredentials) }
        Auth0
            .users(token: accessToken)
            .get(profile!.sub, fields: ["user_metadata"], include: true)
            .start { (result) in
                switch result {
                case .success(let user):
                    print(user)
                    callback(nil)
                case .failure(let error):
                    callback(error)
                }
        }
    }

    func store(credentials: Credentials) -> Bool {
        self.credentials = credentials
        // Store credentials in KeyChain
        return self.credentialsManager.store(credentials: credentials)
    }
}
// also contains standard plist func written by Auth0
```

this is the error I'm getting:

> ---GETMETADATA--- Failed with unknown error ["error": Bad Request, "statusCode": 400, "message": Bad HTTP authentication header format, "errorCode": Bearer]

I know that normally you would use Bearer + accessToken to authenticate but I don't see them use this in the docs or the example project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found out what was wrong. In my case, I needed to use the `/api/v2` endpoint rather than the `/userInfo` endpoint: `.audience("https://" + clientInfo.domain + "/api/v2/")`
I hope this helps future searchers!